# Update UI in closure

Tags: multithreading, swift, closures

I'm trying to update my UI while executing a function with a status closure and a completion closure. The UI is only updated when the closure is complete. I understand that this happens because the operation is not happening on the main thread and the UI need to be updated on the main thread. I have tried moving the UI updates to the main thread, but without any luck. I have included a simplified version of my code.

How can I solve this problem? Will it solve the problem if I specify a custom thread for my code to be excecuted? If so, how is that done?

Thank you very much for taking your time to read.

Code is included below. Let me know if you need any more information regarding this issue.

```
func parse(array: [String], status:(status: String!, progress: Float!) -> (), completion:(result: [String]!) ->()) -> () {

        status(status: "Process is starting.", progress: 0)

        var newArray = [String]()

        for (index, txt) in enumerate(array) {

            //Update status
            let progress = Float(index + 1) / Float(array.count)

            status(status: "Checking string: \(txt)", progress: progress)

            //Do something with txt
            let newTxt = txt + "OK"

            newArray.append(newTxt)

        }

        status(status: "Complete!", progress: 1.0)

        //Send completion
        completion(result: newArray)

    }

    var startArray = [String]()

    for index in 0...10000 {

        startArray.append("\(index)")

    }

    parse(startArray, { (status: String!, progress: Float!) -> () in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            println(status)
            self.statusLabel.text = status

            println(progress)
            self.progressView.progress = progress

        })

        }, { (result: [String]!) -> () in

            println("Process complete. Here is the result:\n\(result)")
    })
```

Comment: I think I got it to work by putting the enumeration array inside another thread like so:
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {}
Is that the correct way to go? Does this come with a catch?

Comment: In this case it looks like `parse` is probably called on the main thread and the status callback is also queuing to the main thread, which means that it won't happen until the parsing is completed.  Make sure that parse isn't being called on the main thread (or within parse force execution to another thread)

Comment: Also note that order of execution isn't guaranteed between threads, so in a situation such as your example, where the parsing is fairly quick with nothing that would yield control, it's entirely possible that it would all execute before the main thread executes again.  One possible solution there would be to use dispatch_sync instead of dispatch_async, which would block the processing thread until status update is performed.

Comment: Excellent answers, David. Thank you. I would like to call parse on another thread, then update my UI on the main thread. It would be nice to force execution on another thread from within parse. What is the best way to accomplish that? So if I understand correctly, dispatch_sync does not block the processing thread? What if my logic in parse is heavier, let's say I'm saving NSEntities to Core Data, what would be the best solution? Thanks again. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that parse was called on the main thread, so when updating the UI, that thread was already blocked. I solved the problem (with the help of David's comments) by putting parse in another thread, then updating the UI on the main thread with GCD.